# Swift 4.2 & observe enum value

Tags: swift, enums, swift4.2

I would like to attach observe for the enum value.

My simple code using integrated into Swift CryptoTokenKit package

This code generating an only .init event
I used the same code for monitoring **slotNames (String array)** and it works perfectly.

So, How to attach observe for this enum state

```
let mng = TKSmartCardSlotManager();
for name in mng.slotNames
{
    print(name)
    mng.getSlot(withName: name)
    { (slot: TKSmartCardSlot?) in
       let _ = slot?.observe(\TKSmartCardSlot.state, options: [.initial, .new], changeHandler: { obj, change in
            print("something")
        })
        slot!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "state", options: [.initial, .new], context: nil)
    }
}
```

link for doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptotokenkit/tksmartcardslot/1390293-state)

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and I found solution

So there is a loop and every object with for example assigned observer must be added to array NSMutableArray. It works now great !